# ViewPager wrong page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I'm making an app with horizontal pages using ViewPager class. Currently, having problems with displaying pages correctly. This code mostly comes from example, with few modifications. I'm not sure how the fragment "switch" should happen, but I got it semi-working at onCreateView. Now when I start app, I get welcome screen, next page is again welcome screen, then page1/2/3. When "moving backwards" it goes like page 3, 2, 3, 2, 1.
Probably there's problem with mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), but I'm clueless why.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        static ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.hide(); 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        }

        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }    
        }
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

            public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
                PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                int page = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                View rootView;
                switch (page) {
                    case 0: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_screen, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 1: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 2: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 3: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 4: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page4, container, false);
                        break;
                    case 5: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page5, container, false);
                        break;
                    default: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_screen, container, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a view in the ViewPager based on which view *the user is looking at*. This is clearly not your intention, because the ViewPager will generate the views when it deems best fit, which is not related to what the user is looking at.

To illustrate this, suppose that the app starts and the user will be looking at page 1. The ViewPager prepares:

- Page at index #0, as that's the one currently showing
- Page at index #1, as that one should be ready to be shown when the user swipes.

However, because you inflate the view based on which item is showing, both of those views will be the welcome page due to this logic:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int page = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    View rootView;
    switch (page) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You should instead select the page index as it's provided from the fragment's arguments:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private int mPage;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        mPage = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        switch (mPage) {
            case 0:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_screen, container, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page4, container, false);
                break;
            case 5:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page5, container, false);
                break;
            default:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_screen, container, false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your given example  in constructor public PlaceholderFragment() args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) aren't yet set as it is done in PlaceholderFragment newInstance after calling the constructor itself.

Comment: @Soapnrope Yes, you're right; it wasn't observing the lifecycle of fragments. I had typed the answer from my phone and hadn't given it any thought. Reading `getArguments()` should be in `onCreate()` as you'll see in the revised code above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass ArrayList< Integer> of the layout xml file id in and  for extends PagerAdapter

```
       public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        ArrayList<Integer> objects=null;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<Integer> objects) {

         this.objects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getItem(int position) {
            return objects.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }    




@Override
public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
            this.objects.get(position), null);




    ((ViewPager) container).addView(convertView);

    return convertView;

}

    }
```

also search for sample like this on google.

Answer (score 0):

you just need a Bundle to keep your data.
for example :this is a instantiate listfragment which contain two params,and then we need to use these two param to instantiate first page in viewpager

```
public static TitleFragment newInstance(int i,int k){
    TitleFragment fragment = new TitleFragment();
    //add Bundle
    PAGE = k;
    NTYPE = i;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("PAGE", PAGE);
    args.putInt("NTYPE", NTYPE);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    Log.d("list", "list" + i);
    return fragment;
}
```

we gain the data in onCreate Method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int SomeInt = getArguments().getInt("PAGE", 1);
    int someTitle = getArguments().getInt("NTYPE", NTYPE);
    list = getNewList(someTitle,SomeInt);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),list,R.layout.news_item);
}
```

It works correctly.